# Snippet to show the error messages on the comment form

Tags: theming, forms, comments

Every form I try to modify with a module loses the ability to display errors during submission. I searched for an option to fix that, and the solution I found was a snippet which uses `form_get_error()` to show the error messages. I added the snippet in a template  file for each form.

Now I need a snippet to use in a template file for the comment form. Which snippet should I use?

Comment: Usually these messages gets ditched from the theme's lack of messages area in page.tpl.php

Comment: I see. I didn't know about that area. and your are right, as soon as I place it on my page.tpl.php the errors ("messages") are in place again. However. I still need to have more control over this messages. In this way they are placed on top of the page and with the custom system css. I will take a look and see if I could come up with someting. But this is a great lead. Thank you.

Comment: I set this in page.tpl.php: <?php global $global_messages; $global_messages = $messages; ?> and I mange to create a template for the comment-form ( comment-form.tpl.php ) global $global_messages; print $global_messages; this way also works for my other forms... But again I find another issue. The comment form is not showing the complete preview. I see the form and I could insert $variables['comment_preview'] = render($variables['form']['comment_preview']); But the current node is not showing. Many post talk about disable preview now I now why. I would like to keep it. Any idea ?

Comment: I have the missing part: $variables['current_article'] = render($variables['form']['#node']);